Apex not pulling all fields for an object with getDescribe
I'm having an issue with retrieving all the fields on an object in apex. So far the only way I have been able to do it is through the running a soql query using the tooling api in the dev console. I'm not sure why.
The apex I have tried is:
Schema.SObjectType objType = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Order');
for ( Schema.SObjectField field : objType.getDescribe().fields.getMap().values() ) {
    Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = field.getDescribe();
    system.debug(fieldResult.getName());
}

Unfortunately this doesn't pull all the fields, even if I have access to them. For example, it doesn't pull the ContractName standard field on the Order object.
When I run this SOQL I get the same result.
SELECT Label, QualifiedApiName from FieldDefinition where EntityDefinition.QualifiedApiName = 'order'
When I run that same SOQL with the tooling api, I do get all of the fields.
Is there a way to get the same result I get with the tooling api through apex?
